# AutoMapper specific value for a property

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map List to List but one of the properties of the DtoLineItem is different.

How can I tell AutoMapper to map a specific property of LineItem to that Property?

I've tried this:

```
CreateMap<Cart, CartModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LineItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LineItems))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LineItems.Select(x => x.CustomField), 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LineItems.Select(y => y.Description)));
```

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException Custom configuration for
>   members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.

Comment: You could just create a map between the two `LineItem` types.

Comment: It's working for the most part, however one specific property is named differently in the destination object. How can I do it?

Comment: Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fA99lG